# Django Pass Extra Information To ManyToMany Model Signal

Tags: python-3.x, django-models, signals, django-signals, django-4.0

i have a manytomany django related models which needs an entry created automatically when one model is created using signals. my challenge is passing extra information to the signal for the intermediate Team model table?

```
class Listing(models.Model):
    """
    The Listing Model
    """

    # model fields --> [name, description, email, phone]

    team = models.ManyToManyField(User, through = 'Team')


class Team(models.Model):
    """
    A Group Of Users To Manage A Listing
    """

    AUTHOR = 'Author'
    EDITOR = 'Editor'

    ROLE_CHOICES = [(AUTHOR, 'Author'), (EDITOR, 'Editor')]

    listing = models.ForeignKey(Listing, on_delete = models.RESTRICT, related_name = 'businesses')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete = models.RESTRICT, related_name = 'buddies')
    role = models.CharField(max_length = 10, choices = ROLE_CHOICES, default = EDITOR)


@receiver(post_save, sender = Listing)
def create_team(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Team.objects.create(listing = instance, author = instance.author, role = 'Author') # <-- How To Pass User Instance To Signal?!
```

How do i pass the user instance to the signal to create author for the listing?

for example `Listing.objects.create(..., author = user)` to create the Listing and it's Author(User)?

**Edit**
A `Listing` is created by a `User`, who is assigned the role of `'Author'` and is part of the `Team` to manage the `Listing`. so whenever i call `Listing.objects.create()`, how can i pass the user to the model to create the `Team` as well using the signal `create_team`, else the listing will be without a `User` i.e `Author`

Comment: The question is not very clear. Can you consider rewording it and adding some extra info about how you would instantiate your objects and what exactly you would expect? Your question implies that a Listing has an author, but your code says a Team has an author so it's a bit unclear

Comment: At the moment of a `post_save`, the `ManyToManyField` relation is *not* yet populated since one first needs to save the item to have a primary key. This is one of the many reason why one better does *not* use signals: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html

Comment: is there a way to do it without using signals? i want it to happen as soon as the `Listing` is created without having to write something like:  `listing = Listing.objects.create(...)` then `Team.objects.create(listing, user, role)`